# How do I access the name of the class of an Object in Python?

Tags: python

The title says it mostly.

If I have an object in Python and want to access the name of the class it is instantiated from is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
obj.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: Except for the annoying underscores (which are a general Python phenomenon).

Comment: What are uncomfortable?  The obvious markers that delineate "internal details"?  How can those essential markers be uncomfortable?

Comment: So I guess __FILE__ and __LINE__ are annoying too? It's not just a Python thing—the underscores are used pretty universally, as far as I know. :/

Comment: Yeah, but Ruby is so much more elegant. obj.class.name :)